# Angularjs Promises in validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-promise

I am working on a workflow engine that has been written in angularjs, between stage changes, I can configure a validation method to run, and the workflow engine expects this validation function to return a boolean value to act for stage changes.

This validation scheme is great, if you are checking user input etc, but if you need to make a call to the server, because of the async nature of these calls, workflow engine does not wait for the result of the call and goes to the next stage.

To prevent this from happening I thought I could make use of promises. And I came up with a validation method like the following, but the problem that I have is I can return true when the async call completes, but it is returned in the inner function.

What I need to achieve is I need to return true from $scope.validate once the async operation completes, I can easily accomplish this with jquery, but I want to make it happen using angularjs and promises, any help would be appreciated:

```
var createPromise;

    $scope.validate = function() {
        createPromise = $scope.createAndGoSales();

        createPromise.then(function(data) {
            return true;
        });
    }

    $scope.createAndGoSales = function () {
        return customservice.createSales({
            ProductChangeId: $scope.model.ProductChange.Id
        }, function (response) {

        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused about a lot of this code. Why are you even bothering to bind `$scope.createAndGoSales()` to `createPromise`? Why not just put `customsservice.createSales` in your `$scope.validate function`? You can still return a boolean value out of the function if the response was successful, and then bind whatever the response is to some data variable.

Comment: customservice.createsales is an async operation, even if I put it inside validate function, I will be able to return a boolean value from its callback, and validate function's return has already been executed at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the promise from validate method and handle it on then of this returned promise.

Comment: I thought about it, but it won't work because the workflow engine does not expect a promise, it expects a boolean value to be returned from the validate method, and I cannot change the source code of the workflow engine.